# Kristin PDF to HTML result into a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

By using Kristin Gem, Is there any possible way to store the result of the conversion on a variable instead of outputting it as a file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the link below goes to the gem you are talking about, no. The gem is a very thin layer on top of pdf2htmlEX and simply spawns the process with the arguments passed. Further, pdf2htmlEX doesn't seem to support redirecting its output and adding this feature doesn't seem to be on their todo list, so adding this functionality would require wrapping a different converter.
I think your best bet would be to save load the HTML to a variable after creation.

Kristin:https://github.com/ricn/kristin
Thread about adding output redirection to pdf2htmlEX: https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/issues/638